# Elastic Search Union Queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to union 2 Elastic search queries. since my queries are sorted separately, it's not possible to do it with and/or and methods like these.
I have news documents, I want to have a result containing:
- Unread news (read = false) sorted by date
- Read News (read = true) sorted by date
Unread news mus be at first and I want to get news with page size of 20, so we may have 3 pages of unread news, 1 page of read+unread news and then 5 pages of read news.
How can I create this query?

Answer (score 1):

use multi search API to run your various queries in single search request.

```
_msearch
```

After receiving results, build result set using user defined algorithm.

Comment: is it possible to help me with the query? It's hard to understand how to do it with msearch

Answer (score 1):

If all your fields you need for sorting are within same type you can use several sorting criteria:

```
POST index/article/_search
{
  "size": 20,
  "sort": [
    {
      "read": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I think you do not understand my mean. you only sorted a query! I want to queries sorted by different criteria and the result will be sequential.